# Is it legal to Spring JpaRepository save to postpone insert?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I use Spring Batch and within step I insert value via `JpaRepository.save()` method.

I enabled:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL: DEBUG
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql: true
```

and all SQL select statements appear in log in same sequence as in code. When I stepped by debugger each `find*` resulted in log event by `org.hibernate.SQL` logger.

But I don't see `insert` SQL statement until I leave String Batch Step. Walking with debugger shown that `insert` logged only after:

```
package org.springframework.transaction.support;

public class TransactionTemplate extends DefaultTransactionDefinition
    ....
    @Override
    public <T> T execute(TransactionCallback<T> action) throws TransactionException {
        ...
        this.transactionManager.commit(status);
```

Is it OK to postpone `insert`? Why Spring/Hibernate didn't to actual `insert` inside transaction and instead delayed this action? Is it Spring or Hibernate feature?

That discovery surprised me. I need to take this into account when troubleshoot problems... Is it possible to disable this Spring Batch or Spring Data or Hibernate magic?

**UPDATE** Here is the trace to magic point:

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
  at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:151)
  at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
  at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
  at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374)
  at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
  at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
  at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
  at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
  at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
  at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
  at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
  at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
  at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
  at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
  at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306)
  at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Yes, it's legal and expected. It allows executing multiple inserts in batch; it allows not executing inserts if the transaction ends up being rolled back; it allows avoiding additional updates if the inserted entity is modified after the call to persist(). Why do you care? And of course, it's a JPA/Hibernate feature. Spring-data just delegates to JPA.

Comment: @JBNizet I looked to logs and found that log events had order that differed from how statements appeared. I was afraid that some bug in App. And this is just feature ))